Play motherboard buzzer in Windows 10/11 x64 using .NET
I am currently developing a .NET service which should use the buzzer of the motherboard depending on some circumstances.
I've tried a lot of solutions including:
SystemSounds.Beep.Play();

Console.Beep();

PowerShell script such as: [console]::beep(600,1000)
Command Prompt script: echo ^G
Also tried the following library: https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/ but am struggling to set it up and run it.

Problem with the previous solutions is that all of them play the beep on my peripherals, not on my motherboard buzzer.

My motherboard has a buzzer - checked it.
Using .NET Framework 4.8
If there is no way to do it using .NET but there is a way using c/c++, I am keen on developing it using c/c++ and then running the program from my .net service
Also: Would be extremely helpful if there is a way to even play the beep constantly.

First check: Does your PC even have a speaker to beep in the first place?

Yes, have it written explicitly: "My motherboard has a buzzer - checked it."

You've listed failures here. What worked to confirm that? The PC speaker, which dates from the original IBM 5150 in 1981, is a really odd thing to use in 2024. Some motherboards include a "beeper" which is used only for BIOS status reports, I'm not sure you can actually beep it via software as you would the PC speaker.

It may seem odd at first sight, but it has an important role considering the purpose of the service I am working on. It would be really disappointing if there is absolutely no way to invoke the PC speaker :(

"My motherboard has a buzzer - checked it." how did you determine that?

Beep function (utilapiset.h)

It's not that unusual... Mine has one which I can drive from Linux using the pcspkr kernel module. I've never tried from windows.

The BaWaMI MIDI Player is a Windows 64-Bit Application that supports using the IBM PC Speaker. I don't know if its written in .NET but maybe you can just look at its code at how it manages to use the IBM PC Speaker and just work your project from there
